# Get a keras model to output a result and another using ma of the weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, moving-average

Given two keras models `model1` and `model2` with identical architectures, I need to train the first using the model weights and the second using the moving average of the model weights. Here's an example to illustrate:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow_addons.optimizers import MovingAverage
import tensorflow as tf


model1 = Model(...)
model2 = tf.keras.models.clone_model(model1)
opt1 = Adam()
opt2 = MovingAverage(Adam())
model1.compile(optimizer=opt1)
model2.compile(optimizer=opt2)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape, tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
    loss = calculate_loss()  # the loss is the same
grads1 = tape.gradient(loss, model1.trainable_variables)
grads2 = tape2.gradient(loss, model2.trainable_variables)
model1.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads1, model1.trainable_variables))
model2.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads2, model2.trainable_variables))
```

After each gradient update, both models will be called on the same input to output separate values.

```
v1 = model1(inp)
v2 = model2(inp)
```

Is it possible to get rid of the dual logic `tape1` and `tape2`, `grads1` and `grads2` ... by merging both models to somehow output both results from the weights and the averaged weights?

Comment: It's unclear what your objective is here. What do you mean by merge 2 models into 1?

Comment: I'll edit to explain. I'm sorry, I ran out of charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you could create two copies of the same network under one model, but under different name scopes, and then at optimization time, use one optimizer to update your `regular` weights, and have another optimizer only update your `moving average` weights.

#### Data

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow_addons.optimizers import MovingAverage
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam


# fake data
X = tf.random.normal([1000, 128])
y = tf.one_hot(
    tf.random.uniform(
        [1000, ],
        minval=0,
        maxval=3,
        dtype=tf.int64), 3)
```

#### Custom Model

```py
# custom model with weights under specific name scopes
class DualWeightModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_units=256):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_units = num_units
        self.x_r = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.num_units)
        self.l_r = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")
        self.x_ma = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.num_units)
        self.l_ma = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")
      
    def call(self, x):
        with tf.name_scope("regular"):
            out_r = self.l_r(self.x_r(x))
        with tf.name_scope("ma"):
            out_ma = self.l_ma(self.x_ma(x))
        return out_r, out_ma
  
  
# loss function
def calc_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()(y_true, y_pred)
```

#### Optimization

```py
# optimizers
opt_r = Adam(1e-4)
opt_ma = MovingAverage(Adam(1e-4))


# instantiate model
model = DualWeightModel()


# define one train step
def train_step(X, y):
    # forward pass
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        y_hat_r, y_hat_ma = model(X)
        r_loss = calc_loss(y, y_hat_r)
        ma_loss = calc_loss(y, y_hat_ma)
        
    # get trainable variables under each name scope
    r_vars = []
    ma_vars = []
    
    for v in model.trainable_variables:
        if 'regular' in v.name:
            r_vars.append(v)
        if 'ma' in v.name:
            ma_vars.append(v)
    
    # optimize
    r_grads = tape.gradient(r_loss, r_vars)
    ma_grads = tape.gradient(ma_loss, ma_vars)

    opt_r.apply_gradients(zip(r_grads, r_vars))
    opt_ma.apply_gradients(zip(ma_grads, ma_vars))
    
    return r_loss, ma_loss
```

#### Train Model

```py
# train
train_iter = iter(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y)).batch(32))

for epoch in range(10):
    r_losses, ma_losses = [], []
    for batch in range(100):
        X_train, y_train = next(train_iter)
        r_loss, ma_loss = train_step(X_train, y_train)
        r_losses.append(r_loss)
        ma_losses.append(ma_loss)
        
        if batch % 5 == 0:
            msg = (f"r_loss: {np.mean(r_losses):.4f} "
                   f"\tma_loss: {np.mean(ma_losses):.4f}")
            print(msg)
            r_losses = []
            ma_losses = []

# r_loss: 1.6749    ma_loss: 1.7274
# r_loss: 1.4319    ma_loss: 1.6590
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very similar to what I'm trying to do. I have a question though, can the loss be shared? I mean can both optimize weights using `r_loss`? And is this approach more efficient than the initial example's?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your first question.
With regards to the second, while I haven't benchmarked or compared the initial example to my solution, I would hypothesize that creating one model with dual weights would be less code, easier to train, easier during inference, etc...

Comment: nevermind, I think your solution does the job, thanks